# How do I strip white space when grabbing a text()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jquery statement. I wish to remove the whitespace as shown below. So if I have a word like:

**For example** 
    "*#wordOperating System/test*" I would like the end result to show me "*#wordOperatingSystemtest*". (ie without slash and space). The slash works fine but I can't get the space to be removed. Please help!

```
$("#word" + lbl.eq(i).text().replace("/","\\/").replace(/ /,'')).hide();
```

Comment: @SA: your statement "the slash works fine" and your code sample do not compute: your code sample does *not* remove forward slashes, rather it replaces each with a preceding backslash `\\`.

Answer (score 3):

Try the [global `g` modifier](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp):

```
.replace(/ /g, '')
```

Same goes for your slash replacement (in case there are multiple `/`s in your string):

```
.replace(/\//g, '\\/')
```

Comment: @Josh: consider the OP's own code sample was replacing `/` with `\/`, which this answer addresses.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with one simple regex...

```
var x = "wordOperating System/test";
x = x.replace(/\s|\//g, '');
alert(x);
```

So your code will be...

```
$("word" + lbl.eq(i).text().replace(/\s|\//g, '')).hide();
```

Comment: okay. May be i am unclear  (i am very new to jquery) but what I want is to have an escape char for space. So if I read text= Operating/System it replace that to Operating\/System when I run the code. In the same way I want to have an esc char for space. So that when it reads a space it adds and escape char for space in the same way. How would I do that. Please help.

Comment: @SA: now you're saying you want to escape spaces? Which is it: remove spaces, remove slashes, *escape* slashes, or *escape* spaces?

Comment: Yes. I ran the code and realized the issue. So when I read a space or s slash  in the string i want to escape slashes and escape 1 space in the string.