# Escape a white space character using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following jquery statement. I wish to remove the whitespace as shown below. So if I have a word like:

**For example**

- `#Operating/System` I would like the
  end result to show me
  `#Operating\/System`. (ie with a
  escape sequence).

- But if I have `#Operating/System test` then I want to show
  `#Operating\/System` + escape
  sequence for space. The `.replace(/ /,'')`
  part is incorrect but `.replace("/","\\/")` works
  well as per my requirements.

Please help!

```
$("#word" + lbl.eq(i).text().replace("/","\\/").replace(/ /,'')).hide();
```

Comment: Glad you got your clarification correct in your head, but you should have just updated your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703529/how-do-i-strip-white-space-when-grabbing-a-text

Comment: Well. I will mark the answer there for future reference. But this is a new question. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: I would (tentatively) say that you are trying to do the wrong thing (or the right thing in the wrong way, which is just as bad). *Why* do you want to escape certain characters in a string?

Comment: I think he wants to dynamically use text on a page as a selector for jQuery.  I agree that there are several potential problems with this.

Comment: Well I am dynamically reading an id (asp.net) which contains slashes and spaces and then hiding those particular selectors with those values.

Comment: what do you mean by "id (asp.net)"? Is this an ID attribute being generated by asp.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$( "#word" + lbl.eq(i).text().replace(/([ /])/g, '\\$1') ).hide();
```

This matches all spaces and slashes in a string (and saves the respective char in group `$1`):

```
/([ /])/g
```

replacement with

```
'\\$1'
```

means a backslash plus the original char in group `$1`.

```
"#Operating/System test".replace(/([ /])/g, '\\$1');
-->
"#Operating\/System\ test"
```

Side advantage - there is only a singe call to `replace()`.

EDIT: As requested by the OP, a short explanation of the regular expression `/([ /])/g`. It breaks down as follows:

```
/           # start of regex literal
  (         # start of match group $1 
    [ /]    # a character class (spaces and slashes)
  )         # end of group $1
/g          # end of regex literal + "global" modifier
```

When used with `replace()` as above, all spaces and slashes are replaced with themselves, preceded by a backslash.

Comment: Well this works fantastic so anything with spaces ex "Operating System" works fine but anything with SLASHES ex. "Operating/System" or "Operating/System test" is not working. Also, I would really really appreciate it if you can explain this replace(/([ /])/g, '\\$1') statement as i don't understand it. Thanks again.

Comment: I've just tested it - for me it replaces slashes as well. How did you test?

Comment: There are no double quotes in my code, and it's not an accident. ;-) You should read a few lines on `replace()` in particular and regular expressions in general.

Comment: @Tomalak. Thank you for the explanation and you are right it works in a single replace for spaces and slashes. You have a mastery over this. Thank you, Thank you, thank you .... again and again. You saved my life today!!